# Cant see printf in mplabX IDE anywhere... Why?

Tags: c, pic, microchip, mplab, pic32

I tried this in a function, but I dont see anywhere the result in MPLAB X IDE. Why? Where I can find the printed result? I am using pic32 Curiosity development board and XC32.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 10;
printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n", a, b);
```

Any info? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider where the code is running

Comment: I am expecting to see it in the output window, but there is nothing there... Do I have to use the simulator if I want to print just a simple text to help me debbug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` always uses the UART as STDOUT. 
If you use the simulator you could enable UART IO under Project Properties. Know it's your choice if you like to see your printed data in a file or in an output window.

Comment: I thought it was possible to use the output window without the Simulator... We all learn from our dumb mistakes.

Comment: Where do I find 'UART IO' in the Project Properties?

Comment: Project Properties / Simulator / UART1 IO Options / Enable Uart IO

Comment: FYI When configured for output window, output goes to the tab "UART 1 Output" of the Output window ... which only shows after output actually goes there

Answer (score 1):

Why?
Because mplabX IDE doesn't have access to your hardware. I guess you use debugging (you haven't written), then your debugging (unit? hardware? software?) might not support it.

Where I can find the printed result?
That depends on how you have written your _mon_putc() function. `By default, MPLAB® XC32's libraries use UART2 for STDOUT.` For example for [PIC32MZ EF CURIOSITY DEVELOPMENT BOARD](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005282B.pdf) UART2 (signal U2TX) would be on pin 7 on MCU, that would be pin 4 on J11 or pin 13 on J10 or pin 5 on connector J14. The best would be to buy a cheap UART<->USB converter to read from that uart.

Any info?
Sure.
[(XC32) How do I instruct printf to output to UART1 or other UART channels instead of UART2?](http://microchipdeveloper.com/faq:81)
[Debugging: Can I redirect printf or putchar to the MPLAB X console?](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m1037661.aspx)
[stdio over uart1 example](https://gist.github.com/raivisr/5007565)
The mplab simulator uses uart1 as stdout and the simulator connects a simulated "reader" to that uart which shows it's output on mplab console. The uart on your real hardware, I guess, isn't anyhow connected to the computer.